# Extension of "Duration of Stay" in a single country within a valid period of a Schengen Visa

Tags: visas, schengen

I have a Schengen visa which is valid between October and November 2017, with *"allowed duration of stay in Czech Republic up to 16 days."*

I wish to stay longer in Czech Republic for another week. There is a big design festival organised and I want to check it out.

Would it be possible to fly out of the Czech Republic for a day or two and then back to Czech Republic to stay longer than 16 days stated in the visa?

Comment: Do you have a multi entry visa?  If they've set a time period on your stay, then I'm going to guess not, but could you confirm?

Comment: It’s a single entry visa. I’ll just go back home and come back again later :)

Answer (score 7):

> My question is: would it be possible to fly out off Czech Repubic for a day or two and then back to Czech Republic to stay longer than 16 days stated in the visa?

No.

The "Duration of Stay" dictates how long you can stay in the Schengen Area between the "From" and "Until" validity dates on the visa or in compliance the 90/180 day rule (depending on which applies in individual cases) - it does not reset on a border hop, it is not per trip, it is total.

https://ec.europa.eu/home-affairs/what-we-do/policies/borders-and-visas/visa-policy/read_visa_sticker_en

Comment: Thank you so much for your clear explanation. So I guess I have no choice apart from waiting to come back for the festival next year.

Answer (score 4):

If it is a multiple entry visa, you can stay for a total of 16 days (the first and the last count as full days) during the period of validity, with a gap in between. So you **can** adjust the dates of your travel as long as you have days left.

- You can postpone your entire trip, arriving later and leaving later, as long as it is within the period of validity.
- If you arrive in the Schengen area later than planned or leave earlier, you might save up a few days for a second visit later on.

This does not apply for a single-entry visa.