# Schengen visa duration of stay: can it be longer than what is quoted on the visa if the visa is valid?

Tags: schengen, indian-citizens, visa-expiration

The duration of stay on my visa is 43 days but it is valid for 58 days. Can I extend my stay for another 8-10 days? It is a single-entry visa.

Comment: Did you do a search of the site? I am pretty sure we have had an identical question just a few weeks ago. Not as new as I thought, but good answers: https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/72395/i-have-a-schengen-visa-valid-for-longer-than-my-allowed-duration-of-stay-can-i This one is the one I thought about: https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/103823/extension-of-duration-of-stay-in-a-single-country-within-a-valid-period-of-a-s

Comment: Duplicate, though I don't see the need to downvote a new user. Find answers on the [Schengen overview page on Meta](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3758/32134).

Comment: No, you can not.